# Using SpriteKit in IOS, how do I implement 'snap' behaviour?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm using SpriteKit to handle a bunch of smallish sprites on screen.  I'd like to tell one of the sprites to 'snap' to a specific location with the same kind of feel as that given by a 'UISnapBehavior' when used on a UIView.  I can apply a 'SKAction moveTo:' but I don't get the 'boing' at the end, which would feel nice.  I feel I'm missing something here as it is surely a common requirement.

Thanks for any help - just a pointer will probably do...!

Answer (score 0):

The bounce in UIKit comes from modeling a spring force. SpriteKit has its own options for modeling spring forces: [`SKPhysicsJointSpring`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsJointSpring_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKPhysicsJointSpring) and the [`springField`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html) constructor on `SKFieldNode`. Which to use depends on just what kind of effect you're going for, whether you want to affect multiple bodies at once, and whether you plan to support iOS 7 or just 8.0 and newer.

You might also investigate using a `moveTo` action with a custom [`timingFunction`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKAction/timingFunction) — it might be possible to get the same "overshoot and bounce back" behavior with a timing function that generates [damped oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement with you, and I used the velocity of physicsBody, it works for me.

```
for node in nodes {
    let p = node.position
    let dx = point.x - p.x
    let dy = point.y - p.y
    node.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
}
```